# Grails throws ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful

Tags: hibernate, grails, h2

The last thing "I remember" before this error appear is updating to openjdk8

```
Error 2015-01-12 14:19:44,751 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table post (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, content varchar(255) not null, limit integer not null, posted_date timestamp not null, poster varchar(255) not null, title varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
| Error 2015-01-12 14:19:44,755 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE POST (ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL, CONTENT VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, LIMIT[*] INTEGER NOT NULL, POSTED_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, POSTER VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, TITLE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID)) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table post (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, content varchar(255) not null, limit integer not null, posted_date timestamp not null, poster varchar(255) not null, title varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) [42001-176]
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/brewee
```

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Grails 2.4.4
- javac 1.8.0_25

**DataSource**

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
```

I am new to grails. Is it right to think that i have done something that close this in-memory db? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put H2 Dialect

`dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"`

In your dataSource block of DataSource.groovy file.It should fix your problem.

Make sure you are not facing [This](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8140) Issue.